# Select from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've been thinking about something these days. I have two tables in my database, and I will call them "fruit" and "color" (very creative names). In the table "fruit" I have two columns named "id" and "name". In the table "color" I have two columns named "id" and "name". That's right, the columns of the two tables have identical names. 
In the column "name" of the table "fruit" I have the ​​"banana" and "strawberry" values. In the column "name" of the  table "color" I have the "yellow" and "red" values​​. 
My question is this: is it possible to select the values ​​of the "name" column of both tables and display as a single outcome, ie, as if it were coming from a single table, such as "banana - strawberry - yellow - red"?

I know that the SELECT will not work, but maybe he can illustrate what I am unable to put into words.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT fruit.name, color.name FROM fruits.fruit, fruits.color";
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($sql):
   echo $line['name'];
endwhile;
?>
```

Note: The tables do not have a foreign key, so you can not use INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN

**----------- CONCLUSION --------------------**

I do not know if it will help anyone, but the answer given by friend [PhillipXT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3175748/phillipxt) is valid and the solution looked like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT fruit.name FROM fruits.fruit UNION SELECT color.name FROM fruits.color";

$ret = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($ret) === 0):
    echo 'Zero results';
else:
    while($line = mysql_fetch_array($ret)):
        echo $line['name'];
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

If I made a "dumb" question is because I'm trying to learn. On the day that I have all the answers, I will not need to dumb questions!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the sample data and desired results (rather then trying to explain them)?  Also, you should change the title to English.

Comment: @Gordon LinoffSorry for the title, I forgot to put in english

Comment: do colour and fruit with the match got same id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UNION query:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Fruit
UNION
SELECT ID, Name FROM Color
```

That will give you all the data from both tables in 2 columns named ID and Name.

Comment: @PhillipXT-thank you my friend, that was exactly what I was trying to do.